# Run "nohup $COMMAND > /dev/null &" with "back $command"

Tags: bash, fedora, bashrc, nohup

I'm trying to setup a script in my .bashrc which would create an alias that makes it possible to run a command in the background and ignores output. It should be possible for this command to have multiple arguments, for example "java -jar MyJar.jar". So far I have tried:
    alias back='nohup "$1" > /dev/null &'
But when I test it using for example
    back sh path/to/intellij/bin/idea.sh
my console output is like this:
    nohup: failed to run command ‘’: No such file or directory
And whenever an error happens, it's also logged, which is what I wanted to avoid. Am I taking the wrong approach here or what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a function instead of an alias like:

```
function back() {
    nohup "$@" &> /dev/null &
}
```

Comment: What does the `&> /dev/null` do here? doesn't the nohup command itself capture all the output into the `nohup.out` file already?

Comment: It prevents the output of `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’`

Comment: Adding this to .bashrc was indeed the solution, and works like a charm.